# How to stop InvalidOperationException from showing when user refreshes the page before the request comes back from .NET Service?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, service

For the past couple of days, I've been getting an error in the Event Viewer Application Log where I log errors in my applciation: `InvalidOperationException: Headers already sent.`. For a while I couldn't replicate it, but I finally discovered that this occurs when an API call to our C# service is made through the test website (written in html and javascript), but the page is refreshed before the request returns to our website. I would like to ignore this error if it happens and not have it show in the Event Log (for clarity reasons during demonstrations). Is it possible to catch such an error when it happens and ignore it? What possible repercussions could this have? If I find out how to catch it, I can instead throw a much more descriptive error that explains what happened. Is this possible?

Note: This error does not interrupt the service and does not appear when running in Debug mode in Visual Studio. The output log just shows `Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll`.

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
ERROR Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump ProcessRequestAsync
System.InvalidOperationException: Headers already sent.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.Response.CheckResponseStarted()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.Response.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at Zeva.WebHelper.ActionResults.AsyncOkResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI\SwaggerUIMiddleware.cs:line 68
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger\SwaggerMiddleware.cs:line 35
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<InvokeCore>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

Comment: You can try to add `CancellationToken` parameter  in your action method and  use `try catch` to catch this TaskCanceledException.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using `CancellationToken`s in your controllers? When using as an argument for an action, they cancel the request when the browser cancels the HTTP request. Take a look at this blogpost: https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/.